# $0 \neq 1$ not provable in axiomatic arithmetic?

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

I am reading my logic professor's notes, and he writes

> What then is the evidence that there are no undiscovered contradictions from axioms of arithmetic? Exactly why is $0 \neq 1$ not provable in an axiomatic arithemic based on a specific list of properties expressed in a language?

This is shortly after he listed the Peano axioms. $1$ is just shorthand for $s(0)$, and we have as an axiom that $(\forall x)\neg(s(x)=0)$. So in particular, $\neg (s(0)=0)$, i.e., $1 \neq 0$. So what could my professor mean when he says $0 \neq 1$ is not provable in an axiomatic arithmetic? It is possible he has misspoken.

Comment: Perhaps you can ask your professor.

Comment: While I do not know what axioms you have, you might try $x \in \{0,1\}$ and use mod-2 arithmetic to see if your axioms are consistent in that case. So in that case $s(0)=1$ and $s(1)=0$, which seems fine as long as you remove that assumption that $s(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: The point is that there might be a long and sophisticated proof of $0 = 1$, which would be a contradiction. The question is how do we know that our axioms are consistent? That is not as obvious as it may seem.

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you, that does seem to be the point he was trying to make.

Answer (score 5):

Your professor misspoke. The doubt is whether "$0=1$" could somehow be proved from the axioms of arithmetic - note that this is equivalent to those axioms being inconsistent. Of course, the statement "$0\not=1$" is very easily provable from those axioms.

Comment: This looks good (I give plus 1, don't know why others downvote).  My interpretation is a bit different though, one could ask "why do we need to include the axiom $s(x) \neq 0$, can't we just prove $s(x) \neq 0$ from the other axioms"?  And I think a simple proof that "it is not provable from the other axioms" is if you define your set of numbers to be something trivial, like the set 0 alone, or the mod-2 binary field, which likely satisfies all other axioms. Overall, the professor is there and likely holds office hours, it makes sense to ask him/her directly!

Comment: @Michael That would be a very reasonable question, but I don't think it's the one the professor was mentioning: "What then is the evidence that there are no undiscovered contradictions from axioms of arithmetic?" is asking about the issue of being able to prove *too many* things from *already given* axioms, not about needing more axioms to prove new things (although of course the issue of sufficiency [is a fundamental point in mathematical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems)!).

Comment: I was focusing on the second sentence of the professor "Exactly why is $0\neq 1$ not provable in an axiomatic arithmetic," which suggested to me the idea of removing this as an axiom and trying to prove it as a lemma. You are convincing that, in view of the first sentence, the "$0\neq 1$" was likely a typo that should have been "$0=1$." This is kind of an interesting "max-likelihood error correction" problem on language.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, another possibility that leapt to mind was that maybe the professor meant to say "Exactly why is $0\not=1$ not **dis**provable in ...", which is the sort of thing I used to say before I figured out why three negatives in a row are a bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

$1 \not = 0$ is not the same statement as $0 \not = 1$, but that is easily fixed, assuming some standard rules of logic:

1. $\forall x \neg s(x) = 0$ Peano Axiom 1
2. $\quad 0 = s(0)$ (Assumption)
3. $\quad 0 = 0$ ($=$ Intro)
4. $\quad s(0) = 0$ ($=$ Elim 2,3)
5. $\quad s(0) \not = 0$ ($\forall$ Elim 1) (i.e. '$1 \not = 0$')
6. $\quad \bot$ ($\bot$ Intro 4,5)
7. $0 \not = s(0)$ ($\neg$ Intro 2-6) (i.e. '$0 \not = 1$')

OK, so it is definitely false that '$0 \not = 1$' is not provable from the Peano Axioms.

But probably your professor meant the following: how do we know our axioms are consistent? How do we know we are not able to infer a contradiction from them (which would be the case if, e.g. '$1=0$' would be provable)?

That's a good question, and the standard answer is that we can come up with a model for the Peano axioms ... which is of course just the domain of natural numbers, together with the successor, addition , and multiplication functions as we know them. And since there is a model, that means it is impossible to derive a contradiction assuming your logical inference rules are sound (as they are for any standard proof system). So, it would be impossible to prove 1=0 or anything else like that that would lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Symmetry of $\neq$ was not part of my confusion.

Comment: @kccu Understood. I updated my answer to address what I think your professor really meant

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but I suspect it is because your original answer did not address my question. However, is it really true that because there is a model it is impossible to derive a contradiction? I thought it was *not* possible to prove the consistency of arithmetic.

Comment: @kccu But we *can* prove the consistency of proof systems, i.e. of logic itself. So, if there is a model for a set of statements, you really cannot derive a contradiction from it (using a sound proof system).

Comment: @kccu Well, how did we know that model exists? Bram28's claim that the naturals form a model of PA relies on the *existence* of the set of natural numbers; this is a statement that needs some axioms to prove. What is true is that any (non-silly) theory which can prove the existence of the set of natural numbers *proves that PA is consistent*. But you're right, you can't get something from nothing - we have to prove that this strange thing called "the natural numbers" exists (and also is a model of PA, but that's usually trivial from existence). (continued)

Comment: What Bram28's argument shows it that we can conclude that PA is consistent *from "basic" assumptions* - it's just that one of those basic assumptions is that the set of natural numbers exists. This is certainly a basic assumption *I* make, and [I would argue that it's a necessary one for doing mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2037877/28111), but it is implicit there. (And I would argue that the statement "PA is consistent" is *not* so obviously true, so it's not silly to say "PA is consistent since the set of natural numbers exists.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you for your comments!  It makes me wonder: is there maybe a way to show that 1=0 cannot be derived using an argument that does not use formal semantics, and speaks to the nature of those derivations directly?  ... but I am guessing any such argument would probably rely on induction? ... and thus somehow on the nature of the natural numbers after all?  Do you have insights about that?

Comment: Wow, it is clear that there is still a lot here I don't understand. Thank you both for your comments!

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, most definitely! (Although of course that deduction itself has to take place in some background theory, so you'll never "catch your tail.") This is a very important subject in proof theory, and is essentially the beginning of **ordinal analysis**. The first result in this direction was [due to Gentzen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentzen%27s_consistency_proof), who showed that the consistency of PA is provable in the weak theory PRA (a very very small fragment of PA) together with a certain transfinite induction axiom - roughly speaking, "induction along $\epsilon_0$."

Comment: The idea behind ordinal analysis is this: given a theory $T$, we analyze the structure of deductions from $T$. We first "thin" the set of deductions to "appropriately nice" ones, and show that anything provable from $T$ has a "nice" proof. It is then usually very easy to show that there are no "nice" proofs of $0=1$, so the whole meat of the argument is in showing that every proof can be made nice; this is the sort of thing [cut elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem) does. This step itself winds up being a transfinite induction on the "ranks" of proofs. (continued)

Comment: The supremum $\theta$ of the ranks of proofs from $T$ is then the *proof-theoretic ordinal of $T$*; and (if you've done everything right) the theory PRA+"induction along $\theta$" (appropriately formalized) will prove the consistency of $T$. Now by Goedel, we'll never have PRA+"induction along $\theta$" actually contained in $T$; but this is still interesting, since usually PRA+"induction along $\theta$" won't contain $T$, either. Incidentally, it's worth noting just how terribly complicated the proof-theoretic ordinals of strong theories can be!

Comment: @NoahSchweber Oh, wow, that sounds terribly complicated indeed! ... And in the end, there is still this "can't catch your tail" feeling left, isn't there?   ... I guess I'll stick to my original argument: natural numbers form a model of PA ... that's a reasonable enough answer to the OP's question, right?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, indeed - and you can find at various places on this site (e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2017578/do-we-have-to-define-natural-numbers-in-geometry?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589992/are-the-natural-numbers-implicit-in-the-construction-of-first-order-logic-if-so?noredirect=1&lq=1)) discussion about that vicious circle (I personally think it's ultimately inescapable, there are many who disagree with me). I do think your answer was spot-on for the OP btw (and have upvoted), I just wanted to clarify based on their

Comment: later question about what is provable where.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Cool, thanks!  I really appreciate you taking the time to talk about this, and thanks for the references ... and I have seen and learned from other posts from you as well, so thanks for all your contributions to the community! :)