# Which combination of Peano axioms shows that $0\neq 1?$

Tags: peano-axioms

> Please vote to close this question. It's really dumb as when I was reading the Peano axioms, axiom 8 didn't register. Don't waste your time reading this question.... I also cannot delete it (I have tried but it won't let me).

$1$ is defined as $S(0).$

An essentially equivalent question to the one I am asking is, "Why isn't $0\neq 1$ a Peano axiom?"

If we accept [Wikipedia's $9$ Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Historical_second-order_formulation), as well as the two axioms of addition, how do we show then that $0\neq 1?$ Or do we need to accept the multiplication axioms *as well* in order to show that $0\neq 1?$
Or is there *another* axiom I am not seeing that you need, in order to show that $0\neq 1?$

Basically, as far as I can tell, none of the axioms tell us that we cannot have $0=1=2=3=\ldots.$

I think that what I am referring to is (essentially?) the group (semigroup? ring?) $\langle \{0\}, + \rangle\ $ along with $=$ defined as an equivalence relation, and an axiom that enables substitution.

$$$$
[$0 \neq 1$ not provable in axiomatic arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2222836/0-neq-1-not-provable-in-axiomatic-arithmetic)

I looked here, but I'm not sure the question is the same as my one and I don't understand the answers. I also don't think the answers relate to wikipedia's version of the Peano axioms, but maybe I am wrong?

Comment: Don't we also have to assume a set theory as well?  In ZFC for instance we know that $0\neq 1$ because $x\neq \{x\}$ by the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @JMoravitz I am not familiar with the set theory formulation of Peano's axioms. Just wikpedia's "standard" approach. I know set theory approach is probably more formal or more correct or whatever, but I am not familiar with it.

Comment: I don’t get all the downvotes. I tried deleting this as soon as the answers came, but you’re not allowed to… Maybe I will ask this as a question on meta

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't want to continue to receive downvotes.

Comment: After thinking about your meta post for a few days, I decided to upvote this.  I believe it is a natural Question to ask about where $0\neq 1$ is implied by the Peano axioms, in spite of it being a central consideration.  You showed some effort in stating the problem by bringing up a trivial model $0=1=2=...$, so with my upvote you now have net positive effect on your reputation.  Not that you should be worried.  The two succinct Answers are also worth keeping!

Comment: @hardmath thank you.

Comment: The linked post is about conflating $\mathsf {PA} \vdash \lnot (0=1)$, that is true (see answer) with $\mathsf {PA} \nvdash (0=1)$ that amounts to consistency of $\mathsf {PA}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Axiom 8 in the Wikipedia list of axioms says that $0$ is not the successor of any natural number. Since $1 = S(0)$, we have $1 \neq 0$.

Comment: Somehow I missed this. Wow.

Answer (score 2):

You only need two of the axioms:

1. *Axiom 1*: $0$ is a natural number.
2. *Axiom 8*: For every natural number $n$, $S(n)=0$ is false.

In particular, the statement of axiom $8$ this is also true for $n=0$ (because, from Axiom 1, we know $n$ is a natural number). Therefore, $S(0)=0$ is false.

Comment: Yes. My brain isn't working properly for me to miss this...