# Proving the induction principle?

Tags: logic, induction

Suppose we have a language that just consists of a term "a" and a successor function s(x). We know that p(a) is true and we know that $\forall x: p(x) \to p(s(x))$ is true. Suppose **we don't have** the induction rule: p(a), $\forall x: p(x) \to p(s(x)) \vdash \forall x: p(x)$. Then we couldn't prove the conclusion $\forall x: p(x)$, could we?

I ask because in some course the prof says: *For the language introduced above, our rule of inference [induction rule] is sound. Suppose we know that a schema is true of a and suppose that we know that, whenever the schema is true of an arbitrary ground term τ, it is also true of the term s(τ). Then, the schema must be true of everything, since there are no other terms in the language.*

IMO he can't write that because he basically claims he can prove the soundness of the induction rule beyond. But as far as I understand you cannot prove the soundness of this rule beyond, i.e. you have to assume (per axiom) it and then you can prove it trivially from the assumption (and of course the assumption could be always wrong so you could never be sure the "schema must be true of everything". Am I right?

Comment: I think you're right.  For example, consider a model in which the interpretation of $s$ is just the identity function.  Or for another example, suppose the language had just the nullary function $a$ - then you certainly can't conclude $\vdash \forall x: x = a$ just because $a$ is the only term with no free variables.

Comment: Another reason we couldn't prove that conclusion without the induction rule is that there are models of (the usual axioms minus induction) that [look very different from the positive integers](https://www.quora.com/What-happens-if-we-eliminate-the-induction-axioms-from-the-Peano-axioms). In those models, the usual base-case and induction-step assertions simply don't prove universal statements, because there are (lots of) elements that are unreachable from a starting point using the successor operation.

Comment: "Then, the schema must be true of everything, since **there are no other terms in the language**."  (emphasis mine) That I think is key.  However we need some axiom or a reason to say that we can "get to" all terms this way and there are no other terms.  It is my understanding that the induction principle is nothing more or less than a statement that there are not terms that can't be gotten this way and therefore all terms can be gotten this way.

Comment: That said I'm not sure I agree with the author either.  But I will have to read the entire statement in context.  (Your argument and understanding is sound, IMO)

Comment: @fleablood So what about nonstandard models of PA, for example, where not all elements are reachable in an absolute sense, yet the induction axiom schema still holds essentially because there are no *definable* subsets which distinguish the reachable elements from the nonreachable elements?

Comment: @DanielSchepler I think you answered your own question.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Counterexample to the argument that $\forall x \ p(x)$ logically follows from $p(a)$ and $\forall x (p(x) \to p(s(x)))$:

Take as the domain all non-negative integers, interpret $a$ as $1$, $s$ as the successor function, and $p(x)$ as $x$ is a positive integer. Then the premises hold, but since $0$ is not a positive integer, the conclusion does not.

Comment: Not sure I understand your counter example. It's a counter example due to a lack of base case and not any fault of induction principal.

Answer (score 1):

> We know that $p(a)$ is true and we know that $\forall x: p(x) \to p(s(x))$ is true.

If there also exists $b$ in the domain of discussion that is distinct from $a$, then, without the induction schema, you could not rule out $s(a)=a$, $s(b)=b$ and $\neg p(b)$. It would be vacuously true that $p(b) \to p(s(b))$.

**EDIT:** In answer to your follow-up question: What if $a$ is the only object in the domain of discussion? Then $P(x)$ will be true for all $x$ in the domain of discussion. Here, $U(x)$ means that $x$ is an object in the domain of discussion.

Proof: (Induction not required)

[image]

Comment: I almost provided this exact same counterexample but chose to go with the numbers

Comment: @Bram28 That's reassuring. :^)

Comment: But what if there exists no $b$ in our domain. I claim we still could not prove $\forall x: p(x)$ without an induction rule. Otherwise the induction rule wouldn't be a rule/axiom, but just a theorem, right? Also it would make no practical sense in the Peano-Axioms, that define IN precisely ("no b's besides a"), to insert an induction axiom if the stuff could be proven in a simpler way.

Comment: If $a$ is the only element of your domain of discussion, and we know that $p(a)$ is true, then, of course you could infer that $\forall x: p(x)$.

Comment: How? Remember: Even if we only have 'a', we still have s(a), s(s(a)),.... I don't see a chance to prove $\forall x: p(x)$ without the induction axiom. Otherwise it wouldn't be the induction axiom, but the proven induction theory.

Comment: Anybody? IMO Dan Christensen is wrong, but if I am wrong I need to know. :)

Comment: There is no need to consider s(a), s(s(a)), etc.

Comment: Well, we have infinitely many objects in our world: a, s(a), s(s(a)), .... Let's just assume for the sake of the argument all those objects have the property P. But how could we prove that if we don't have an induction axiom? IMO impossible. Can u describe your idea of how the proof would look like? Why and how could u infer from P(a) to the universal statement P(x)?

Comment: @Pippen See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what else the professor said, since there is a specific sense in which he is correct.

It is true that we **cannot** possibly justify induction in a **non-circular** way. See [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1334753/21820) for more details, but I wish to quote a single key part of that post:

> The second [circularity] is the understanding of the arithmetic on the natural numbers including induction. This boils down to the understanding of "repeat". If you do not know the meaning of "repeat" or "again" or other forms, **no explanation can pin it down**.

Think about it; there is no way to explaining how to repeat something an arbitrary finite number of times without relying on prior understanding of natural numbers including induction.

However, we **can** justify adding the induction axiom schema to [PA$^-$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#Equivalent_axiomatizations), though this justification will rely on **meta-induction** on the length of finite strings. Specifically, if you can define the natural numbers to be exactly those that can be written in the form "$0+1+\cdots+1$" for **some number** of "$+1$"s, then the natural numbers also obey the induction axiom schema. See [this post](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/10033/1550) for details. Note that such a definition **requires assumptions** that are at least as strong as induction.

For example, in ZFC we can construct the intersection of all inductive sets, using the one given by the axiom of infinity. But such a construction is in fact **impredicative**, which is even less philosophically justifiable than induction; if you doubt induction holds for natural numbers, you will certainly not believe that the axiom of infinity plus such impredicative constructions are valid.

On the other hand, we can assume that we can construct the set of strings that can be generated starting from "$0$" by appending "$+1$". This is equivalent to having induction, but some logicians prefer this generative form (also known as inductive constructions) to the axiomatic form (i.e. the induction schema).

To summarize the intuitive reasoning in the linked post:

> If every natural number is of the form "$0+1+\cdots+1$" for some number of "$+1$"s, then the induction rule is sound because the conclusion it gives us is true for every natural number $k$, since we can construct a proof that uses the induction step $k$ times to deduce the desired statement about $k$.

Constructing such a proof of course requires induction, but hopefully you can see why it is possible **if** you believe in the existence of the set of all strings of the form "$0+1+\cdots+1$" for some number of "$+1$"s. So I think that the professor is referring to the **term model**. Indeed, **if** there is **only** one constant-symbol $0$ and one function-symbol $s$ in the language (and no others) and there is a term model, **then** for any first-order property $Q$ over the language, if that term model satisfies ( $Q(0) ∧ ∀k ( Q(k) ⇒ Q(s(k)) )$ ) then it also satisfies $∀k ( Q(k) )$, precisely for the reason that every element in the term model is generated by $s$ from $0$.

Also note that the meta-reasoning only tells us that there exists a proof for each natural $k$, and not that there is a proof for the universal statement, and furthermore the existence of a proof does **not** imply truth unless you also assume the soundness of the system without induction.

Comment: 1. If we have a language {a, s-function}, i.e. terms a, s(a), s(s(a)),... then we can only prove a property for all those terms if we have an induction rule, right? 2. The induction rule is no tautology like basically all other proof techniques (e.g. raa = P -> (A & ~A) -> ~P) and I feel that very fact renders it an inferior proof, am I right?

Comment: (1) No, because it may be possible to prove some facts without induction, due to other axioms. (2) Induction is not tautologous, but neither are any other axioms, so I don't know what you're referring to as "inferior".

Comment: Just look at the linked axiomatization of PA$^-$. It has a list of many axioms, none of which are tautologies. That's not "inferior". Rather, that's what we **want** because we **believe** that our conception of natural numbers **satisfies** those axioms. Similarly, we **believe** that it is sensible to think of natural numbers as those that can be generated from $0$ by adding $1$, so we **ought to believe** that induction holds as well. Nothing "inferior" at all. @Pippen